# django-orm : How can I insert element to a table of a particular database

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

I have 2 different database in setting.py. 
To do select operation I use following statement and is working fine:

```
all_data = Bugs.objects.using('database_one').filter(reporter=user_id, bug_status='resolved', resolution__in=all_resolutions)[:2]
```

But how can I pass the database value to insert an entry in the table of same database.

I tried this but this doesn't seems to be working:

```
row_to_be_added = TableName(pr=pr, case=case, comments=comments).using('bugzilla').save()
```

Can anyone please help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-for-save):

```
row_to_be_added = TableName(pr=pr, case=case, comments=comments).save(using='bugzilla')
```